# Cache coherency for geo distributed key-value caches

Tags: redis, synchronization, cloud, key-value, distributed-caching

I am looking for a distributed caching solution which supports a MOESI/MOESIF-like implemementation of a cache coherency protocol.

Our caching nodes are distributed over they globe and as a result see large latencies between them. So a distributed cache which partitions the keyspace would not work if we can not influence the placement of individual keys (e.g. Redis Cluster).

I am thinking about a cluster in which modifications of a certain key will invalidate all other copies of that key which might be cached by other nodes.
Pretty much a version of MOESI/MOESIF but at a larger scale (cloud vs chip).

Does somebody know a key-value db or distributed cache which would support this?

My current best bet is to implement this functionality on top of Redis by implementing a small proxy which implements the coherency between multiple Redis instances.

Comment: Did you check the Redis Active-Active solution? https://redislabs.com/redis-enterprise/technology/active-active-geo-distribution/

Comment: Sounds interesting. But it has two drawbacks:
- Its only included in Redis Enterprise? And is not Open Source?
- It replicates the full keyspace?

Comment: Yes it is part of the Redis Enterprise , but it compatible with Redis Opens Source APIs. And it replicates the full keyspace